# How to check multiple URLSearchParams with a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html

So this is my current script:

```js
    new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
        if (name == "UserID") {
            let Value1
            if (!Value1) {
                Value1 = value
                document.getElementById("Welcome").innerText = `Welcome, UserName#0000 (${Value1})`
            }
        } else {
            if (name == "UserName") {
            let Value2
            if (!Value2) {
                Value2 = value
                document.getElementById("Welcome").innerText = `Welcome, ${Value2}#0000 (${Value1})`
            }
        }
        }
    })
```

This code will detect the first part in the url but not the second. This is the url: `http://127.0.0.1:5500/UserVerification/index.html?UserID=1236128738716233&UserName=UrMom&UserDiscriminator=2810` and with this it will not detect the UserName neither the UserDiscriminator. Why?

Comment: What do you want to appear if both the UserID and UserName exist? Eg from your example, what do you want the contents of `Welcome` to be?

Comment: I want it to be: Welcome, UserName#UserDiscriminator (UserID)

Comment: `let Value1; if(!Value1)` <= the variable will always not have a value.  You didn't give it one.  That conditional is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `.get()`.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
document.getElementById("Welcome").textContent = 
 `Welcome, ${params.get('UserName') ?? 'default value'}#${params.get('UserDiscriminator') ?? 'default value'} (${params.get('UserID') ?? 'default value'})`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `Value1` and `Value2` with `let` which will make them block-scoped. But the bigger issue is that they are in a callback function, and thus their values don't persist between calls.

Try declaring them outside the `forEach()` loop. I've added a few additional lines for debugging:

```
var s = 'UserID=1236128738716233&UserName=UrMom&UserDiscriminator=2810';

var Value1
var Value2
new URLSearchParams(s).forEach((value, name) => {
    console.log("GOT: " + name + '=' + value);
    if (name == "UserID") {
        if (!Value1) {
            Value1 = value
            console.log(`1: Welcome, UserName#0000 (${Value1})`)
        }
    } else {
        if (name == "UserName") {
            if (!Value2) {
                Value2 = value
                console.log(`2: Welcome, ${Value2}#0000 (${Value1})`)
            }
        }
    }
})
```